# Invoking a Process On server startup

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I have a process which I will be invoking manually for the first time in prod environment. Thing is, the process stops when the server is down or if the server is stopped. In this scenario, I will not be able to invoke the process manually everytime since it will be in production environment and not feasible also. So i need to know how can i invoke a process automatically once the server is up?
Heard that one way is to write a custom component to start the process using livecycle implementation class.
Please let me know how to go about it?

Any help regarding this is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways you can do this.

- First is the custom component route. You invoke the process on component life-cycle start to ensure that the invocation happens every time your component is deployed.
- Second is the servlet route. You invoke the process on the initialisation of the servlet making sure that the server started.

The servlet implementation is a better fit for purpose, the only downside is, you need to package and deploy it separately as it won't be a part of the LCAs.

You can find the code samples on how to invoke LC processes using APIs on adobe docs. You can use Java API, WS API or Rest, whichever you are more comfortable with.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm